# Sqlalchemy relation with dynamic condition

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Can't figure out how to specify the join condition during the query.
My models:

```
class ListinoDetail(ModelsBase):
    __tablename__ = 'listino_detail'

    ....
    id_articolo = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey('articolo.id_articolo')
    )
    id_listino = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey('listino.id_key')
    )
    prezzo_base = Column(DOUBLE_PRECISION, default=0)


class Articolo(ModelsBase):
    __tablename__ = 'articolo'

    id_articolo = Column(
        Integer,
        Sequence('articolo_id_articolo_seq'),
        primary_key=True
    )
    .....

    prezzo = relationship('ListinoDetail', uselist=False)
```

Now i need to filter for example `ListinoDetail.id_listino = 1` so i can access `articolo.prezzo` and retrieve the current price

Is there a way to do this or i need to load every price and filter next?

The query should be something like this

```
select *
from articolo ar
join listino_detail ld
on ar.id_articolo = ld.id_articolo
where id_articolo = 12345 and id_listino = 1;
```

Comment: Look up using explicit joins and `contains_eager()`.